# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" with mocha

Tags: node.js, typescript, macos, mocha.js, webstorm

I've read all similar questions and ts-node [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node/v/10.9.1#err_unknown_file_extension).
I've tried everything but nothing works

I have TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Documents/WebStorm/new-api-test/tests/pet.spec.ts
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofbG.png)

```
 at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:76:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:118:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:21:20)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:407:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:326:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:66:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:345:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:304:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
    at async formattedImport (/Documents/WebStorm/new-api-test/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:7:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (/Documents/WebStorm/new-api-test/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:38:28)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/Documents/WebStorm/new-api-test/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:91:20)
    at async singleRun (/Documents/WebStorm/new-api-test/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (/Documents/WebStorm/new-api-test/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:370:5)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "new-api-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ts-node/register ./tests/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "got": "^12.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
"target": "ES2020",
"module": "commonJS",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outFile": "./build",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"skipLibCheck": true
},
}
```

**Please help me!**

Comment: error means that you are trying to execute the `.ts` file directly, without pre-compiling. How do you run your tests? please share a screenshot of your run configuration plus the full console content (both the command and error message)

Comment: I use WebStorm, and in the terminal I run the "npm test" command. Screenshot was added to the description

Comment: @astallavista were you able to resolve this issue? I'm running into the same error with mocha.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a problem with ESM support (https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935). `got` package is native [ESM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and no longer provides a CommonJS export